# Sync between different Civicrm dbs

Tags: contacts, extension

We are looking for a way for multiple branches of our organization to maintain separate CiviCRM installs while syncing a particular group of contacts with each other. WE thought of using Mailchimp to hold the master list and have each install sync with that. BUt the current extension only seems to handle fname,lname and email fields.

Long ago some posted this:
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=3070.0.html
which describes a similar need.

Is there any code already developed for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any shared code for this currently. We are working with a client in Aus to build such a system for them which would involve sharing (pushing/pulling) data from the 'parent' crm to various 'child' crm databases.

If you need a solution then we may be able to extract the work we have done that relates to just the features you need but would clearly need to charge and would provide an estimate if you were interested. You can contact me via https://www.fuzion.co.nz/helping-those-who-do-good-do-better or https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/messages/@petednz-fuzion